# How to write class for processing an annotation for fields?

Tags: java, spring, validation, aop, spring-aop

I've created the annotation I want to put on some fields of a class.
I want the annotation to check one of two or more fields:

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OneOfFields {
}
```

For example - the class:

```
public class MyClassRq {
    @OneOfFields
    private String stringOne;

    @OneOfFields
    private String stringTwo;
}
```

If I create an HttpRequest with the body and set both fields, I want to get an exception, javax.validation exception is also possible.

What is the best way to write the validator?

Answer (score 1):

Annotations can be processed in two phases:

- At compile time (in this case through an [Annotation Processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder))
- At runtime (in this case through reflection)

It depends on when you want to perform the check. Considering that it seems you want to check this at runtime (i.e. when you receive the object), then you could create a sample method that takes an object, scans all the fields of the object for the annotation `@OneOfFields` and if more than one is not `null`, then it throws an exception:

```
public static <T> T validate(T input) {
    try {
        int numberOfAnnotatedNonNull = 0;
        for (Field field : input.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(OneOfFields.class) && (field.get(input) != null)) {
                numberOfAnnotatedNonNull++;
                if (numberOfAnnotatedNonNull > 1) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("More than one field annotated by @OneOfFields has been set for this object");
                }
            }
        }
        return input;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not validate input object", e);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
MyClassRq myClassRq = validate(yourInput);
```

If the above `yourInput` of type `MyClassRq` is valid, then it will simply return the same object. Else, it will throw an exception.

Some notes:

- Here I'm throwing as soon as I find more than one field which is non `null`. You may of course create a cleaner error message (for example by collecting all the fields which are illegally set and returning their names)
- Here I'm throwing a standard `IllegalStateException` but you can (you should probably) create your own custom exception
- Don't forget to check that `T input` is not `null` (if it is, my code will crash).
- This is a sample usage of the standard Java Reflect API, there are several ways of reaching the same purpose (I've just shown you the most "readable")